# Getting 'AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on <module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'' this error while executing ML project

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle

**AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on** 
Showing error in `model = pickle.load(open('rf_regression_model.pkl', 'rb'))` this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a new version of sklearn to load a model which was trained by an old version of sklearn.

So, the options are:

- Retrain the model with current version of sklearn if you have the
  training script and data
- Or fall back to the lower sklearn version
  reported in the warning message

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('rf_regression_model','rb') as f:
    model=pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Can you some more details of your model. Thanks

Comment: I am getting some warnings with this error also like:- FutureWarning: The sklearn.ensemble.forest module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.ensemble. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.ensemble is now part of the private API.