# Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on <module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

I obtained the following error:

[image: AttributeError Image]

I don't know what it means.

> Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on <module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation' from 'C:\Users\xyzxy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py'>

Comment: Was your pickle created on this system, or some other system?  This is one of the dangers of `pickle`.  If the snapshot was created on a system with a different version of the modules, things may have changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702362/getting-attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-deprecationdict-on-module-sklea